# Angular 2: JQuery change not changing the binded variables value

Tags: jquery, typescript, angular2-forms

I have a lot of input fields in a form. One of which is

```
<input type="text" name="client_openingbalance" 
[(ngModel)]="client.openingbalance" class="form-control">
```

Using jQuery I am modifying the value of this input field

```
$('.validateForm').on('keypress focusout paste','input',function(event){
        event.target.value = 100;
});
```

But unfortunately, this change is not reflected in **client.openingbalance**. Now, to achieve this I tried to add following lines of code.

```
$('.validateForm').on('keypress focusout paste','input',function(event){
        event.target.value = 100;
        $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

But is still not triggering ngModel. I cannot go and write code for every field.

> Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to bind with jquery, rather than using the angular ng bindings?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$('.validateForm input').on('keypress focusout paste',function(event){
        event.target.value = 100;
});
```

and the event will trigger for every `input` inside `.validateForm`.

let me know

Comment: can u update your question with the current not-working-code? the snippet I gave you indeed triggers on any `input` inside `.validateForm` on any of `keypress focusout paste` events